# How to change Navigation Bar color in Android source?

Tags: android

Editing this ancient question for reputation:

I am reading AOKP source, to help myself, and would like to know where the actual creation of the Navigation Bar is located. In particular would like to change the color of the bar. Where can I locate the Navigation Bar class in the Android source code? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC the SystemUI is responsible for rendering the navigation bar. See [here](http://developer.android.com/design/get-started/ui-overview.html)

Comment: THANKS! Now by chance do you know how where in systemUI it is built? like what Smali/Java file

Comment: @TylerKlein should be https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/packages/SystemUI/